# Как можно сделать выборку из базы данных MS SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте!
Имеется схема базы данных должников по предметам в университете.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня интересует следующая выборка:

> Для каждой группы выбрать общее количество должников и количество
>   должников, у которых количество долгов больше двух
>   Основные таблицы, которые участвуют в запросе:

- **Students**(StudentId(PK), GroupNumber, RecordBookNumber(номер зачетки), FirstName, LastName, MiddleName)
- **Subjects**(SubjectId(PK), Name)
- **StudentsSubjects**(StudentsSubjectsId(PK), SubjectId(FK), TeacherId(FK), MarkId(FK), ControlTypeId(FK), ControlPeriod(FK), CuratorID(FK))

Вывести некоторые данные по отдельности у меня получается.

Количество долгов в группе

```
select Students.GroupNumber as groupNum, Count(StudentsSubjects.StId) as Kol_dolgov
from StudentsSubjects, Students
where Students.RecordBookNumber = StudentsSubjects.StId
group by Students.GroupNumber
order by groupNum
```

Количество должников, у которых количество долгов более двух

```
select t1.Grp, count(t1.Rbn) as Kol_dol_bol2
from
(select Students.GroupNumber as Grp, Students.RecordBookNumber as Rbn, count(StudentsSubjects.SubjId) as Kol_dolg
from Students,StudentsSubjects, Subjects</li>
where Students.RecordBookNumber = StudentsSubjects.StId and Subjects.SubjectId = StudentsSubjects.SubjId
group by Students.RecordBookNumber, Students.GroupNumber
having count(StudentsSubjects.SubjId) > 2) as t1
group by t1.Grp
```

Количество должников в группе

```
select Students.GroupNumber as Grp, count(Students.RecordBookNumber) as Kol_dolgnikov
from Students
group by Students.GroupNumber
order by 1
```

Но не могу никак объединить всё это в одну таблицу. Могли бы Вы подсказать, как это сделать и возможно ли вообще, учитывая данную схему БД.

Comment: UNION *(9 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Менее правильный: создать представление (View), поместив в него необходимые поля из таблиц и поля, полученные при группировках.
2. Более правильный: написать хранимую процедуру, которая будет объединять несколько SELECT в одну общую таблицу.

Известно, что правильно написанные хранимые процедуры работают быстрее, чем представления за счет сохранения плана выполнения.

Comment: А остальные планы запросов разве не кэшируются?

Comment: Я использовал `left outer join`. `select .... from (...) as table1, left outer join (...) as table2 on table1.Номер_группы = table2.Номер_группы`. В итоге получил тот результат, который мне и требовался. В данном случае такое решение может являться верным?